# RegEx only numbers and unit add problem with backspace

Tags: jquery, html, regex

How i can create a Input a field that accepts only numbers and always add unit at the end?

A solution for accepts only numbers using regex is:

HTML:

```
    <input name="distance">
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
     $('input[name="distance"]').on('input', function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/^([\d]+)$/g, '$1 km');
    });
```

Works fine, but some problem occours when i tried to use backspace to correct the information.

Comment: Are you trying to use `\d` as a literal backslash and character d, or for the `digit` shorthand?  Because if you are using it for the shorthand `[\d]` doesn't make sense because `\d === [0-9]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the cursor at the end of the number value, in this case is `-3` from the end of the input value due to the string " km".

Also check if the cursor exceeds the number value (if the cursor is within the appended string " km"), if so, move the cursor to the end of the number value.

```js
$('input[name="distance"]').on('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/^([\d]+)$/g, '$1 km');

  var fieldInput = $(this);
  var fldLength = fieldInput.val().length;
  fieldInput.focus();

  var pos = fieldInput[0].selectionStart;
  // if cursor position is past the number value, reset the cursor to the end of the number value.
  if (pos > fldLength - 3) {
    fieldInput[0].setSelectionRange(fldLength - 3, fldLength - 3);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="distance">
```

Comment: Oh, look's amazing solution! Thx

Comment: @EvandsonDantas I edited my answer to include checking where the position of the cursor is, if it is past the number value, that is when we will reposition it. This allows the user to edit in the middle of the value if need be.

Answer (score 3):

#### Alternative without editing input

Possibly easier and more concise would be to display the units to the right of the input box (or *in* it) as I show in the snippet below.

This method is much simpler and often easier for a user to understand (better in terms of UI).

I also changed the regex from `[^0-9]` to `\D` (since they're identical, just `\D` is shorter).

```js
$('input[name="distance"]').on('input', function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
});
```

```css
*,input {
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input {
  padding-right:1.5em;
  text-align:right;
}
input ~ span.unit {
  margin-left:-1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='distance'/><span class=unit>km</span>
```

---

#### Input type=number

Adding to the above logic, you can also use `<input type=number />` and drop jQuery altogether as the following snippet suggests.

All current browsers support this input type: [Mozilla input number documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

```css
*,input {
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input {
  padding-right:1.5em;
  text-align:right;
}
input ~ span.unit {
  margin-left:-1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=number /><span class=unit>km</span>
```